# Excel graph "show empty cells as: Connect data points with line" behavior with formula

Tags: excel

[excel] How to create the graph "show empty cells as: Connect data points with line" behavior when the cell contains a formula that cannot return "empty" but "" as best.

Comment: It depends. Often you can mimic it by returning `NA()` instead of `""`

Comment: Thanks, this is a working solution. But then I have to live with an ugly #N/A is my table instead of my previously nicer "-"

Comment: You could hide them with conditional formatting

Comment: Both of me?? :)